# Iframe display issue with xml file

Tags: php, javascript, xml, iframe

Certain scores get processed in javascript and then being send trough:

```
window.location.href="scores.php?Result="+result+"&slain="+slain;
```

So next they can be called into php with dom trough GET

```
$name_value = $xml->createTextNode($_GET['name']);
```

All the writing and reading XML wise is working as it should.

But the problem is trying do display the php file into a iframe.

When the user ends the program the scores will get displayed and the link will be something like this:

```
scores.php?Result="1"&slain="5"
```

But how can i display something like that in a iframe, since that query string will always be random.
Although the entire score table is always visible to the user at the end, the idea would just be to display this entire table into a iframe.

How would i be able to show this file into a iframe?

```
<iframe src ="functions.php" width="100%" height="100"/>
// gives errors at src declartion
```

Comment: I wish I could understand what you are trying to do. You just want to display the results of functions.php (or is it scores.php?) on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

@Maelr: You could dynamically create the `iframe` --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // processing of form / scores and setting of result and slain variables...

    // create iframe
    var element = document.createElement("iframe");
    element.setAttribute('id', 'scoresframe');
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.setAttribute('src', 'scores.php?Result=' + result + '&slain=' + slain);
</script>
```